# How can I prove $|x|-|y|\le|x-y|$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

You don’t say whether the numbers are real or complex. Assuming that $|x|\ge|y|$ (otherwise the result is trivial) the inequality is equivalent to $|x|\le|y| + |x-y|$.

Let $z = x-y$, then $x = z+y$ and the inequality is equivalent to $|y+z|\le|y| + |z|$. This is known as the triangle inequality and, for complex numbers, it is clear geometrically as the length of each side of a triangle is less than the sum of the other two sides. In the special case of real numbers (or whenever y and z are on the same straight line), the triangle degenerates to a line, but the result is still true.

Note that if $|y|\ge|x|$ then, by the same reasoning, $|y| - |x|\ge|y-x|$. Combining these cases,$ | |x| - |y| |\le|x-y|\le|x| + |y|.$ (The last part follows by putting $w = -y$ in the triangle inequality.)

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking if your proof is correct?

Comment: Also what's wrong with the following proof?

Subtract |y| >= y >= -|y| from |x| >= x >= -|x|

Get: |x| - |y| >= (x-y) >= - (|x| - |y|)

From the theorm: if a >= x >= -a then |x| <= a

Get: |x| - |y| >= |x-y| ,which a wrong result!!

Comment: What's wrong with your comment is that if $a > b$ and $c > d$, it is not necessarily true that $a-c > b-d$; consider $a = 1, b = 0, c = 2, d = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the triangle inequality holds,

$$
|x| = |x + y - y| \leq |x+y| + |-y| = |x+y| + |y|
$$

Which is essentially the proof that you argued without the introduction of the new label $z$, and it works on any normed vector space.

Answer (score 0):

$$
|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|
$$

$$
(|x|-|y|)^2 \leq |x-y|^2
$$

$$
x^2-2|x||y|+y^2 \leq x^2-y^2
$$

By theorem $|x| \ge |y|$, the result follows immediately from $-2|x||y|+y^2 \leq -y^2$.